# Merge the fiddler and fiddler2

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There are 625 questions tagged with [fiddler](/questions/tagged/fiddler) and 17 tagged with [fiddler2](/questions/tagged/fiddler2). Both are references to the exact same software. "fiddler2" is the name for the current version of Fiddler under .NET 2, while "fiddler4" is the name for the current version under NET 4.0, but in both cases the actual program is called "Fiddler".

The tag wiki for [fiddler2](/questions/tagged/fiddler2)  already has a proposed edit recommending it not be used.

It should probably be merged with, and made a synonym of, [fiddler](/questions/tagged/fiddler).

UPDATE:

As suggested by j0k I have retagged all the existing [fiddler2](/questions/tagged/fiddler2) questions. I don't have enough tag score to suggest synonyms but I think it would be a good idea for [fiddler2](/questions/tagged/fiddler2) and probably also [fiddler4](/questions/tagged/fiddler4) to become synonyms of [fiddler](/questions/tagged/fiddler).

Comment: Are there any instances where there is a difference between the two versions? Are there more features in 'fiddler 4' for example? Just trying to make an argument for keeping the distinction but on the whole I agree with you.

Comment: AFAIK there are none except for the dependency on the Framework. Also note there is not "fiddler4" tag, and the "fiddler" tag actually calls the program "fiddler2" in a few places.

Comment: I think my mistake with the tags only adds strength to your argument. Merge the tags and remove any potential ambiguity and confusion.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield why don't you retag the few 17 questions on your own? Since the author, EricLaw, already stated that [tag:fiddler2] shouldn't be used

Comment: I found no difference between 2 and 4 (i didn't test all, of course, but didn't notice any change on UI, features i do use), and as @KutuluMike pointed, even the 4 calls itself 2 in some parts. Seems just a .NET requirement more than a version. Even with that, i think that no one should point to fiddler itself, should be fiddler2 and fiddler4, case not all .NET functions will cause the same kind of problems... explicit is better than just remove ambigüity.